# Using Comparator with 3 conditions at the same time

Tags: java, sorting

I am trying to create a class which implements the `Comparator` class.

The thing is that I have a list with some objects. This object is composed of 3 fields (Strings). My purpose is to sort the list based first on the first field: if the first field is the same on the two objects that I am comparing at the moment, then compare the second item of the 2 objects and finally if both fields are the same, compare the third field of the objects.

This is what I have done but I do not know if this is the correct answer:

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<Object>{

    @Override
    public int compare(final Dto address1, final Dto address2) {
        int result = 0;

        if (dto instanceof Dto) {
            final Dto dto = (Dto) address;
            final Dto dto2 = (Dto) address2;
            if(dto.getName() < dto2.getName()) {
                 result = -1;
            } else if(dto.getName() > dto2.getName()) {
                result = 1;
            } else {
                result = 0;
            }
        } 
//if the Names are the same then compare the Number
            if (result == 0) {
                if(dto.Number() < dto2.Number()) {
                    result = -1;
                } else if(dto.Number() > dto2.Number()) {
                    result = 1;
                } else {
                    result = 0;
                }
            } 
        //if the Numbers are the same then compare the Other Field

        if (result == 0) {
            if(dto.Other() < dto2.Other()) {
                result = -1;
            } else if(dto.Other() > dto2.Other()) {
                result = 1;
            } else {
                result = 0;
            }
        } 

return result

}
```

Then I will use the following way in my service:

```
Collections.sort(out,new MyComparator());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your implementation:

1. Use `Comparator<Dto>`, not `Comparator<Object>`. Then there is no reason for check for instanceof. And the compiler will prevent you from trying to sort a collection of any other type of object.
2. Relational operators don't work for strings (which `getName()` obviously returns).
3. Null checking is needed.

Following is an implementation that might actually work:

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<Dto> {
    @Override
    public int compare(final Dto address1, final Dto address2) {
        if (address1 == null && address2 == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (address1 == null && address2 != null) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (address1 != null && address2 == null) {
            return 1;
        }

        // here we know that both address1 and address2 are not null
        int result = 0;
        final String name1 = address1.getName();
        final String name2 = address2.getName();

        if (name1 == null && name2 == null) {
            result = 0;
        } else if (name1 == null && name2 != null) {
            result = -1;
        } else if (name1 != null && name2 == null) {
            result = 1;
        }
        else {
            result = name1.compareTo(name2);
        }

        //if the Names are the same then compare the Number
        if (result == 0) {
            if (address1.Number() < address2.Number()) {
                result = -1;
            } else if (address1.Number() > address2.Number()) {
                result = 1;
            } else {
                result = 0;
            }
        }

        //if the Numbers are the same then compare the Other Field
        if (result == 0) {
            if (address1.Other() < address2.Other()) {
                result = -1;
            } else if (address1.Other() > address2.Other()) {
                result = 1;
            } else {
                result = 0;
            }
        }

        return result;
}
```

This assumes that `Number()` and `Other()` return some sort of base type (e.g., `int`).

Another possibility, if you have control over the `Dto` class, is to have `Dto` implement `Comparator<Dto>`, then put the compare method in that class. Then you can simply do

```
Collections.sort(out);
```

assuming out is a collection of `Dto` objects.

Comment: if Dto.getName() is guaranteed to not be null (by contract) then you don't need to check it for null.

Answer (score 5):

The shortest way to do this is using the Java 8 Comparator building api :

```
Comparator<Dto> myComparator = Comparator.comparing(Dto::getName)
    .thenComparing(Dto::Number)
    .thenComparing(Dto::Other);
```

And this is even a lot more readable.

Btw : your method names do not follow Java coding conventions, and the posted code doesn't actually compile.

Answer (score 1):

> This is what I have done but I do not know if this is the correct answer

The idea is perfectly fine, the implementation less so.

```
if (dto instanceof Dto) {
    final Dto dto = (Dto) address;
```

This makes no sense and can't compile. Such `instanceof` checks are needed in equals but not on `compare`.

```
        final Dto dto = (Dto) address;
        final Dto dto2 = (Dto) address2;
```

Switch on warnings, all the casts are unnecessary.

```
       if(dto.getName() < dto2.getName()) {
```

Have you numbered everyone? Otherwise this can't compile.

```
//if the Names are the same then compare the Number
        if (result == 0) {
            if(dto.Number() < dto2.Number()) {
                result = -1;
            } else if(dto.Number() > dto2.Number()) {
                result = 1;
            } else {
                result = 0;
            }
```

This is OK, except for the spacing (missing spaces after `//` and `if`) and naming (this is not C#, method names start with lowercase).

An early return like

```
if (result == 0) return result;
```

would make it a bit clearer. However, you structured it well.

---

But there's a much simpler solution using [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava):

```
import com.google.common.collect.ComparisonChain;
...

public int compare(final Dto address1, final Dto address2) {
    return ComparisonChain.start()
        .compare(address1.getName(), address2.getName())
        .compare(address1.getNumber(), address2.getNumber())
        .compare(address1.getOther(), address2.getOther())
        .result();
}
```

Nice, isn't it (Guava makes a lot of things much easier)?